# Is there no further development on H2?

Tags: database, h2

The last released version was on 2019-10-14.

1. Has development been abandoned?
2. Is the last release (1.4.200) the most stable release with no issues?

Comment: You'll probably get more answers in the Google group: https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database. The [last commit](https://github.com/h2database/h2database) was seven days ago. So something is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it isn't abandoned, but intervals between releases are relatively large these days.
2. H2 compiled from the current sources is actually more stable than any release from 1.4 series of releases, but it is also not compatible with 1.4.200 in various aspects and has some not yet resolved regressions. It's storage format is also different and is still a subject to change. If we talk about the released versions it's hard to say what version has less issues, in some cases 1.4.199 can be more reliable. But in any case you shouldn't try to use multiple versions of H2 with the same database file. Also if you use an embedded persistent database you should not call `Thread.interrupt()` for threads that work with database unless you use the `async` file system abstraction layer. Usually it is safer to use the separate H2 Server process, but client-server model is also slower.